# Error making C++ functions virtual

Tags: c++

The error states:

"error: virtual outside class definition"

Cpp members in question:

```
virtual void Account::creditBalance(double plus)
{
   if(plus > 0)
      balance += plus;
   else
      cout << "Cannot credit negative.";
}

virtual void Account::debitBalance(double minus)
{
   if(minus <= balance)
      balance -= minus;
   else
      cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance.";
}
```

The rest of the code is here (although I'm not sure it's necessary): http://pastebin.com/de5e9f77

Comment: Thanks everyone, I don't know why I didn't figure that out by reading the error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply strip the virtual off of the method definition.  The `virtual` keyword is only necessary at the declaration.

Example:

```
class Account {
public:
  virtual void creditBalance(double);
  virtual void debitBalance(double);
};

void Account::creditBalance(double plus)
{
   if(plus > 0)
      balance += plus;
   else
      cout << "Cannot credit negative.";
}

void Account::debitBalance(double minus)
{
   if(minus <= balance)
      balance -= minus;
   else
      cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance.";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use the virtual keyword inside the class declaration, i.e. in the header file. So change your cpp file to something like:

```
void Account::creditBalance(double plus)
{
   if(plus > 0)
      balance += plus;
   else
      cout << "Cannot credit negative.";
}

void Account::debitBalance(double minus)
{
   if(minus <= balance)
      balance -= minus;
   else
      cout << "Debit amount exceeded account balance.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the virtual keyword only in decleration (in header files, within class definition) and not in implementation (.cc files usually)